# All new Plaster needed for unmodernised Victorian Terrace?

Tags: walls, lath-and-plaster

I've seen and am tempted to put an offer on a (mostly) unmodernised Victorian terraced house in London, UK.

The interior walls are a bit of a state.. layers of paint and wallpaper, and where the paper is peeling the plaster is freely coming away.

Does this imply that all the interior walls would need all the plaster removing and re-rendering?

Im just unsure of the options really. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to answer in general, and hard to answer in specific without actually seeing it. Photos would help, but seriously, I'd suggest you bring in a pro (or several pros) for advice and estimates. After they tell you what the options are for that specific situation, you can decide how much or how little you want to do yourself.

In the US, I'd suggest having this done as part of the inspection process since that estimate can become a bargaining point when setting the final price of the house.

Comment: Thankyou i appreciate the feedback. Unfortunately i only had a brief viewing and this terrible photo is all i have got.. http://imgur.com/1J604yh

Comment: Ask them for a second look, scheduled so you can bring someone along to give you expert advice. If you can take the time to ask here, you can take the time for that.... Yes, it means spending some money even if you don't buy the place, but it sounds like an investment you should make before deciding. (On this side of the puddle we negotiate a basic price first, then get the building inspected and rough quotes on fixing things, then negotiate again around the edges based on what the inspection finds... or walk away if we can't agree.)